# Remove parts of url with htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following url:

`http://www.trashtheweb.com/index.php/home/archive/?p=1`

I would like to rewrite this into `http://www.trashtheweb.com/archive/?p=1`

I tried the following, but this is giving me 404 errors.

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^index.php/home/(.*)$ $1
```

Comment: Not the problem, but please note that the first argument of RewriteRule is a regular expression. Escape any dots that shouldn't match all characters! What does this rewrite to? Does it solve itself when you define `RewriteBase /`? You could try to debug by temporary redirecting instead (`[R]`) and looking where it takes you.

Comment: Is `http://www.trashtheweb.com/archive/?p=1` a working URL for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php/home/(.*)$ $1 [L,R=301,QSA]
```

This code do the job (tried on a blank configuration). If not, you probably have some other files interfering.

Comment: Hi, it does rewrite it to the correct url, but i guess the way my mvc structure is setup messes it up :( Ill accept your answer tho because it exactly does what i asked